# Call function on self with dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Hello**

So, I have some JS code that creates HTML elements dynamically. More precisely, it creates `div` elements that also have some other things inside them.

Each of these `div` elements has an `img` element inside them. How can I achieve such effect, that when the `img` element is clicked in a certain `div` element, that exact div element is deleted?

This is my code which creates elements dynamically:

```js
function addQuestion(question){
    var s = "<div style=\"width:100%;background-color:transparent;border-top:none;border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:none;border-left:none;\"><div style=\"margin:5px;font-family:Verdana;color:white;\">"+"<p>"+noTag(question)+"</p>"+"</div></div>";

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = s;
    document.getElementById("div_questions").appendChild(div);
}
```

Currently it does not create the `img` element. But the idea is that in each of these `div` elements it also creates an `img` element which, when clicked, deletes **that and only that** `div` element.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Also to remove div, you can use `$(this).closest('Div_selector').remove()`

Comment: Where is the img tag added? Don't see an img element in your dynamically added content.

Answer (score 0):

try following code....

```
            var _cotainerDiv = document.getElementsById("holderDiv");

            var _tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
            $(_tempDiv).css({
                //Css properties...
            });

            _cotainerDiv.appendChild(_tempDiv);

            var _tempImg = new Image();
            _tempImg.src = "...../imagePath";
            _tempImg.onload=function(){
                this.addEventListener("click", onImageClick);
            }
            _tempDiv.appendChild(_tempImg);


            function onImageClick(event)
            {
                var _curImg = event.target;

                _cotainerDiv.removeChild(_curImg.parentElement);
            }
```